# Tethered VPN Connection

Tags: wi-fi, tethering, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering

I have an OPPO find 7. At my school we have a pretty mean wifi restriction on the wifi (Blocked websites). Basically I tried to tether through an usb cable from my Phone (while connected to the school wifi) to the computer. I then had a VPN connected that is specific for tethering, but some reason my websites are still blocked. Is there anyway around this or solutions?

I forgot mention that this phone doesn't have cellular connection; strictly wifi only. Also this phone is Rooted.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the DNS servers of the wifi connection.

To change the DNS settings:

1. Open the Settings on the device.
2. Select “Wi-Fi”.
3. Long press your current network, then select “Modify network”.
4. Mark “Show advanced options” check box.
5. Change “IP settings” to “Static”
6. Add the DNS servers IPs to the “DNS 1”, and “DNS 2” fields

Example Google DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (Disconnect wifi then connect again and check if it works)

Alternatively you can change to another better VPN, if it is not configured to work via tethering then activate it but performing the following commands in terminal as root:

```
Iptables -t filter -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I'll try this soon! Thank you for the answer! :D